# Could someone create a tmap tag?

Tags: support

[This Q&A](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/26861/21027) is about tmap, but there is no such tag. Could someone create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sufficient rep, you can create one yourself. :-)

Since you lack that on SQA, I made it for you. Note that if there isn't another question with tmap in 6 months, the tag will get eaten by the roomba.